# VBA index out of bounds error, but not on debugging

Tags: excel, vba

I have some code which takes data from 2 different sheets, and creates and output sheet. The problem is, if a new page in the data is created, it has to do a little additional information, and changes where the page break is. When I run the code with debugging active to see which line of code is causing the error, it works just fine.

When I let it run without debugging, it will give me an error that an index is out of bounds.

I have uploaded the excel sheet itself to https://www.dropbox.com/s/pcl5zwuna8g7wrf/Test.xlsm?dl=0 but I just don't understand why it results in different outputs depending on stepping through it or not, as it is single threaded anyway?

It happens when pressing the button on the fourth sheet.

I uploaded the code to pastebin at: https://pastebin.com/rMwi7c7G

```
Public Function SeitenNr(rngZelle As Range) As Integer
  Dim wksHor As Integer, wksVert As Integer, SeiteNr As Integer
  Dim VertPb As Object, HortPb As Object
  Dim lngOrder As Long

  lngOrder = rngZelle.Parent.PageSetup.Order
  wksVert = rngZelle.Parent.VPageBreaks.Count + 1
  wksHor = rngZelle.Parent.HPageBreaks.Count + 1

  SeiteNr = 1
  For Each VertPb In rngZelle.Parent.VPageBreaks
    If VertPb.Location.Column > rngZelle.Column Then Exit For
    SeiteNr = SeiteNr + IIf(lngOrder = xlDownThenOver, wksHor, 1)
  Next VertPb
  For Each HortPb In rngZelle.Parent.HPageBreaks
    If HortPb.Location.Row > rngZelle.Row Then Exit For
    SeiteNr = SeiteNr + IIf(lngOrder = xlDownThenOver, 1, wksVert)
  Next HortPb
  SeitenNr = SeiteNr
End Function

Sub updateOutput()
    'Sheets("Print-Macro").UsedRange.ClearContents
    'Sheets("Print-Macro").Cells.UnMerge
    Application.DisplayAlerts = False
    Sheets("Print-Macro").Delete
    Application.DisplayAlerts = True
    Dim sheet As Worksheet
    Set sheet = Sheets.Add
    sheet.Name = "Print-Macro"

    Dim indexMain As Integer
    Dim currentIndex As Integer

    Dim artistName As String
    Dim artistNameLast As String
    Dim cellIndexOutput As Integer
    Dim birthdate As String
    Dim deathdate As String
    Dim originalPage As Integer
    Dim currentPage As Integer
    Dim latestPage As Integer
    Dim lastArtistPage As Integer
    Dim birthIndex As Integer
    Dim firstPageArtist As Integer

    indexMain = 2
    cellIndexOutput = 1
    Set f = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Print-Macro")

    Do
        Sheets("Print-Macro").Rows(cellIndexOutput).RowHeight = 15
        Set artistNameCell = Sheets("Was").Cells(indexMain, 1)
        If IsEmpty(artistNameCell.Value) Then
            Exit Do
        End If

        'Code only gets here if a valid entry is found. So create the output now
        artistName = artistNameCell.Value
        birthdate = ""
        deathdate = ""

        If artistNameLast <> artistName Then
            birthIndex = 2
            Do
                Dim tempName As String
                tempName = Sheets("Geboren").Cells(birthIndex, 1).Value
                If IsEmpty(Sheets("Geboren").Cells(birthIndex, 1).Value) Then
                    Exit Do
                End If

                If (tempName = artistName) Then
                    birthdate = Sheets("Geboren").Cells(birthIndex, 2).Value
                    deathdate = Sheets("Geboren").Cells(birthIndex, 3).Value
                End If
                birthIndex = birthIndex + 1
            Loop

            Sheets("Print-Macro").Range("A" & cellIndexOutput & ":" & "C" & cellIndexOutput).Merge
            Sheets("Print-Macro").Cells(cellIndexOutput, 1).Value = artistName & " (" & birthdate & "-" & deathdate & ")"
            Sheets("Print-Macro").Cells(cellIndexOutput, 1).Font.Underline = xlUnderlineStyleSingle
            lastArtistPage = Sheets("Print-Macro").HPageBreaks.Count
            firstPageArtist = cellIndexOutput
            cellIndexOutput = cellIndexOutput + 1
            Sheets("Print-Macro").Rows(cellIndexOutput).RowHeight = 15
        End If

        Sheets("Print-Macro").Rows(cellIndexOutput).RowHeight = 20

        Sheets("Print-Macro").Cells(cellIndexOutput, 2).Value = Sheets("Was").Cells(indexMain, 2).Value
        Sheets("Print-Macro").Cells(cellIndexOutput, 2).Font.Underline = xlUnderlineStyleNone

        Sheets("Print-Macro").Cells(cellIndexOutput, 3).Value = Sheets("Was").Cells(indexMain, 3).Value
        Sheets("Print-Macro").Cells(cellIndexOutput, 3).Font.Underline = xlUnderlineStyleNone

        cellIndexOutput = cellIndexOutput + 1
        Sheets("Print-Macro").Rows(cellIndexOutput).RowHeight = 15

        Sheets("Print-Macro").Cells(cellIndexOutput, 2).Value = Sheets("Was").Cells(indexMain, 4).Value
        Sheets("Print-Macro").Cells(cellIndexOutput, 2).Font.Underline = xlUnderlineStyleNone

        Sheets("Print-Macro").Cells(cellIndexOutput, 3).Value = Sheets("Was").Cells(indexMain, 5).Value
        Sheets("Print-Macro").Cells(cellIndexOutput, 3).Font.Underline = xlUnderlineStyleNone


        ' A page break happened in the last two lines it appears
        If lastArtistPage <> Sheets("Print-Macro").HPageBreaks.Count Then
            If cellIndexOutput = firstPageArtist + 2 Then
                f.Rows(firstPageArtist).PageBreak = xlPageBreakManual
            Else
                Set f = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Print-Macro")
                Dim lastBreak As Integer
                lastBreak = f.HPageBreaks(f.HPageBreaks.Count).Location.Row
                If lastBreak = cellIndexOutput Then
                    Sheets("Print-Macro").Range("A" & f.HPageBreaks(f.HPageBreaks.Count).Location.Row - 1).EntireRow.Insert
                    cellIndexOutput = cellIndexOutput + 1
                End If

                Sheets("Print-Macro").Range("A" & f.HPageBreaks(f.HPageBreaks.Count).Location.Row).EntireRow.Insert

                f.Rows(lastBreak).PageBreak = xlPageBreakManual

                Sheets("Print-Macro").Range("A" & lastBreak & ":" & "C" & lastBreak).Merge
                Sheets("Print-Macro").Range("A" & lastBreak & ":" & "C" & lastBreak).Value = "Noch " & artistName
                Sheets("Print-Macro").Range("A" & lastBreak & ":" & "C" & lastBreak).Font.Underline = xlUnderlineStyleSingle
                cellIndexOutput = cellIndexOutput + 1
            End If
        End If

        lastArtistPage = Sheets("Print-Macro").HPageBreaks.Count

        For i = 1 To f.HPageBreaks.Count
             Worksheets("Print-Macro").Cells(i, 4).Value = f.HPageBreaks(i).Location.Row
         Next

        latestPage = currentPage

        cellIndexOutput = cellIndexOutput + 1
        artistNameLast = artistName
        indexMain = indexMain + 1
    Loop
End Sub
```

Comment: Couple of comments for starters. You do a `Do` loop but then you put an `If` in there to exit the loop, why not just use a `Do Until` loop? `Do Until IsEmpty(Sheets("Was").Cells(indexMain, 1))` Also I notice a lot of Integers being setup, use `Long` in VBA, there are well documented reasons why we don't use integers in VBA. Lastly, `Dim sheet As Worksheet` I wouldn't be using sheet as a variable name, use sht like everyone else or MySheet. Try to avoid using words that are used for Objects, Properties or Methods.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a [known Excel bug](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/210663/you-receive-a-subscript-out-of-range-error-message-when-you-use-hpageb).

A workaround is to select a far enough cell, e.g. the bottom right one, before accessing the `HPageBreaks` collection:

```
Dim previousActiveCell As Range
Set previousActiveCell = ActiveCell
f.Cells(f.Rows.Count, f.Columns.Count).Activate
Dim lastBreak As Integer
lastBreak = f.HPageBreaks(f.HPageBreaks.Count).Location.Row
previousActiveCell.Activate
```

Answer (score 0):

This is where it crashes:

```
lastBreak = f.HPageBreaks(f.HPageBreaks.Count).Location.Row
```

But it only does it when indexMain = 58

After your first do loop starts straight after this line:

```
    Set artistNameCell = Sheets("Was").Cells(indexMain, 1)
```

Put this:

```
    If indexMain = 58 Then Stop
```

This will put the code into debug mode, then step through line by line with F8 and you will see it crash.

If this doesn't give you enough direction to find the issue post back and I will dig further into your code.